# Error in Runge-Kutta 4 solution

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to solve a system of ODE's using the Runge-Kutta 4 Method (RK4). I am code testing the algorithm below, and finding that the solution does not equal the analytical solution (and the error is large). Below I have included my code testing for the I.V.P. dy/dt = f(t,y). I have tried finding errors in this code, but cannot spot them. Any help is much appreciated. 
    globals 
    [t
    dt
    growth-rate]

```
turtles-own [ state ]

to setup
clear-all
create-turtles 1 [ set state 1]
set dt .01
set growth-rate .05
reset-ticks
end

to go
tick
set t t + dt
ask turtles [ set state rk4 t state dt ]    ;integrate the diff eq.
end

;differential equation to be integrated using rk4
to-report df [ t_n state_n ]   ; i.v.p. y(dot) = f(t_n, y_n)
report growth-rate * (state_n)
end


;;;;;;;function calls

to-report rk4 [ t_n state_n h ]
let k1 df t_n state_n
let k2 df (t_n + 0.5 * h) (state_n + ((h / 2) * k1))
let k3 df (t_n + 0.5 * h) (state_n + ((h / 2) * k2))
let k4 df (t_n +       h) (state_n +            k3)
let state_n+1 state_n + ((h / 6) * (k1 + (2 * k2) + (2 * k3) + k4))
report state_n+1
end
```

Integrating this function to t=100, I have an error of > 7 (numerical solution ~156, and analytical solution ~148)

Comment: Also, I should comment, this error is independent of the time step. Thus making me believe it is a problem with how the algorithm is implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the implementation is basically fine, but your interpretation of how many ticks you need may be out. If you change your go statement to the below code, it works

```
to go
ask turtles [ set state rk4 t state dt ]    ;integrate the diff eq.
set t t + dt
tick
if ticks = steps / dt [ stop ]
end
```

You should ahve `set t t + dt` after the state update, because state_n+1 is calculated from state_n at t_n and having the time update first makes it based on t_n+1. In practice, however, that doesn't fix the problem (or make any real difference to the values). But think about getting from t_0 to t_1. You need to go through 1/dt ticks.

So I think when you explain the problem with your example of integrating to t=100, you are actually integrating to t=101. But I am not sure because you didn't provide that bit of your model.